# OpenCV 3.4: OpenCL on RaspberryPi 4 GPU

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, opencl, gpgpu, face-detection

I'm implementing FaceDetection on a RaspberryPi in C++ with OpenCV and now trying to use the GPU by using the OpenCL interface. I'm using haarcascade-feature for the face detection and `UMat` frame-types for opencl-access.

Some technical overview:

1. Raspberry Pi 4
2. OpenCV 3.4.7
3. GPU: OpenCL for the Raspberry Pi VideoCore IV GPU (OpenCL 1.2)

If I'm running the application on the board with *sudo ./app* I get following errors

```
OpenCL program build log: imgproc/color_rgb
Status -3: CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE
-D depth=0 -D scn=3 -D PIX_PER_WI_Y=1 -D dcn=1 -D bidx=0 -D STRIPE_SIZE=1

OpenCL program build log: imgproc/histogram
Status -3: CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE
-D BINS=256 -D HISTS_COUNT=1 -D WGS=12 -D kercn=4 -D T=int -D HAVE_SRC_CONT
```

Using `strace` I found out that some opencl-cache bin-files are missing regarding color_rgb and histogram.

Anyone who can help with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Which OpenCL implementation are you using ? to my knowledge, Pi4 doesn't have any OpenCL GPU support yet.

> GPU: OpenCL for the Raspberry Pi VideoCore IV GPU

I think you are mistaken here. Raspberry Pi 4 has VideoCore **VI** (VC6) not  VideoCore IV (VC4).
I'm guessing you're trying to use VC4CL, but the [project github](https://github.com/doe300/VC4CL) explicitly says it doesn't work with Pi4:

> NOTE: VC4CL will NOT work with Raspberry Pi 4, since it has an incompatible GPU!

Comment: The Raspberry Pi 4 I'm using is a Model B and I got the gpu information from 'clinfo'-command (which is working fine btw). But you're right didn't get it through my research

Comment: I switched to Raspberry Pi 3 and still got the same issue so this could be more a software problem?